# Javascript : window.open : Increase height+width according to the page/body content

Tags: javascript

Ok....Client given me the task to increase the height+width according the body/page content.

Whatever I am doing is onclick of link I am calling following function i.e. `open_bug_add_window`. The function opening one window using `window.open()` method of javascript.

Following is my function:

```
function open_bug_add_window(exec_id)
{        
    height="270px";
    width="510px";    
    window.open(fRoot+"lib/execute/bugAdd.php?exec_id="+exec_id,"bug_add",
        "width="+width+",height="+height+",resizable=yes,dependent=yes, scrollbars=yes");
}
```

Here I am passing `height` and `width` manually to it so its opening window according to that size. But window containing some links and on clicking that links it showing the page. I want to increase the window size according to the page/body contents. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Here you can find a function for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.resizeTo

Comment: @Teemu : Can I use window.resizeTo in window.open(), if yes then how?

Comment: Hmm... Nope. I supposed you're loading a page, window size  according to dimensions in the `window.open` arguments, then have a link in that page which loads a new page, which finally needs resize the window. You put that `resizeTo ()` into that last file, ofcourse, unless you're calculating the height and the width beforehand, and hardcode them to the `window.open()` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using an onLoad event to get the document width and height then set the window size to the document size.

Comment: Can you please give me one example?

Comment: @Ultimate user1906108's example is maybe a bit coarce (`resizeTo(100000,100000)`!!?), but it includes all elements you need for the task.

Comment: @Teemu : Ok but where should I put my url?

Comment: @Teemu : I mean : `fRoot+"lib/execute/bugAdd.php?exec_id="+exec_id`

Comment: @Teemu : Then its opening window in separate tag

Comment: @Teemu : I want to open window in same tag

Comment: @Ultimate Then there is not much you can do. User can decide, whether he opens new windows in new tab or new window. You can find settings for that from your browser.

Comment: @Teemu : Ok Thanks I'll search for it

Comment: It only works with urls in the same domain,resizeTo(100000,100000) needs because of the elements to load in their size.